# DOM remove method in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to change remove a certain tag with an id in the html page, eg.`<div id="theid"><p>sometext</p></div>`
 Is there any ways to do it with react js? I know I can do it with javascript by `document.getElementById("theid").remove();`, how can I do it in the react way? I don't need a button or anything, just simply remove it when the page loads. I'd prefer methods without importing any modules or libraries if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should likely use a ref:

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

So you attach the ref to the DOM element, then you can imperatively remove that element just like you specified.

So in the component function body:

```
const myRef = useRef();
```

Then in the component render:

```
<Component ref={myRef} />
```

Then you can use the code in your question to remove the element from the DOM.

```
ref.remove();
```

If you need to do it when the page loads look at using useEffect to achieve this. Although if you're removing an element on page load, I question why you even need the element there in the first place ;).

Comment: thank you for you insight, as for why I need it in the first place, it is something that is generated from another js file, and is needed by other webpages, so I can't just remove it from my source code.

Comment: Right thanks for the clarification, it sounds like what are you doing is best then. 

If you can't add a ref to the element then I think what you're doing inside a useEffect with an empty dependency array is your best bet.

useEffect(() => {document.getElementById("theid").remove();},[])

Or something like that, let me know if you want a JS fiddle or anything like that.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

You'll want to use the empty dependency array ([]) so that it only fires on component load (once).

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you are willing to make a jsfiddle, I'm totally new to react js.

Comment: Working on it :).

Comment: https://codepen.io/john-mcaulay/pen/oNodGxB 

I added a 2 second timeout on the remove so you can see it actualy being removed.

Let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Thank you! I think that should work. Again, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!^^

Comment: Sweet thanks, if you wouldn't mind marking this as the answer if you're happy ;).

Answer (score 1):

If it's rendered as part of React, the right way to do it would be to simply omit it from the source code:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div id="theid">foo</div>
    <div>more content</div>
  </div>
);
```

to

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div>more content</div>
  </div>
);
```

If it's not part of React, then remove it from whatever process generates the HTML.

If that's not an option - if it must be part of the HTML served to the client and it's not rendered as part of React - then you'll have to resort to doing what you're currently doing:

```
document.getElementById("theid").remove();
```

probably completely separate from your React script, since it's something you want to do only once, when the page loads, and not something that needs to be a part of the React lifecycles.

Comment: it is something that is generated from another js file, and is needed by other webpages, so I can't just remove it from my source code.

Comment: The best approach would be to refactor that other file so that it only creates the element on pages that it needs to be on, instead of everywhere.

Comment: yes I had also thought about that approach actually, but in fact I only have one and only one webpage which needs removing the element, so I thought it might be easier by removing it with js.